# Discord.py ignore specified channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've got this code which logs deleted messages to a channel in my discord. However, I'd like to know how I could make it ignore one specified channel, which I do not wish for it to log deleted messages from. What would I need to edit into my code to do this? Thanks.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(message.author), description=" ", color=0x55246c)
    embed.add_field(name= message.content ,value="Message logging coded by ProfessorAdams.", inline=True)
    channel=bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

If you could let me know what to add to this code to make it ignore one channel, but work for every other channel, that would be amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the deleted message channel id is equal to the channel id that you want it to ignore.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.channel.id == <IGNORED_CHANNEL_ID>: #Enter the channel id that you want to ignore
        return
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(message.author), description=" ", color=0x55246c)
    embed.add_field(name= message.content ,value="Message logging coded by ProfessorAdams.", inline=True)
    channel=bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```